# Soldering to data bus of DDR3 ram

Tags: soldering, ram

Lets say I solder a 2 inch, 30 AWG wire to each data pin on a DDR3 RAM module.
Would this damage the RAM module enough to make it useless?
Would the added resistance because of the wire cause a problem, and could you fix it by just adding series termination resistors?
Are there any other things that would damage the RAM?

Comment: Unless you're particularly ham-fisted with your soldering, it's unlikely that you'd permanently damage the module physically. But it's fairly likely that wires would mess up the signal integrity enough that actually using the memory would be highly unreliable.

Comment: Why though what makes soldering cables onto the data pin so difficult, apart from it being so small?

Comment: Because the chips are designed to be soldered directly to a PCB. Using a PCB makes it possible to tightly control the impedance and timing characteristics of the connections, resulting in a system that works reliably and repeatably. If you're trying to breadboard a system, use SRAM -- it's much more forgiving.

Comment: If you want to use a common DIMM-RAM: There are purpose built extension cables available. If you insist on soldering: If you get the impedances correct and your soldering is somewhat precise - 2 inches could work. But i would go with the DIMM-RAM extension cable.

Comment: at what clock rates are you intending to operate your DDR3? I'm having a hard time imagining a use case where you need such modern, high-speed RAM, but would have speeds low enough that you can operate them through wire instead of short or impedance-controlled PCB traces.

Comment: I think some of you may have missunderstood me. I'm not trying to use the wire to connect it to the slot I just want to use the ram module normally and have an extra wire on each pin to intercept the data written/read on the ram module for analysis.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post a picture of the memory module and the connector.